# コメントをカラムに保存ができない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

初めて投稿させて頂きます。初学者ですが何卒宜しくお願い致します。

現在写真投稿機能を追加しており、その詳細画面（showアクション）からコメントを投稿できるように機能実装を行っています。
そこで、コメントを記述し「投稿する」ボタンを押すと、何も変化がなくカラムにも投稿をしようとした文字は保存されていない状態となってしまっています。

コメント用コントローラー

```
class CatPostCommentsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @cat_post_comment = CatPostComment.create(cat_comment_params)
    if @cat_post_comment.save
      render "/cat_main/#{cat_post_comment.cat_post.id}"
    end
  end

  private
  def cat_comment_params
    params.require(:cat_post).permit(:cat_post_comment).merge(user_id: current_user.id, cat_post_id: params[:cat_post_id])
  end
end
```

コメントモデル

```
class CatPostComment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :cat_post

  validates :cat_post_comment, presence: true
end
```

showのビューファイル（コメント投稿用）

```
  <div class="container">
      <%= form_with(model: [@cat_post_comment,@cat_post], url:cat_main_cat_post_comments_path(@cat_post), method: :post, local: true) do |form| %>
        <%= form.text_area :cat_post_comment, placeholder: "コメントする" %>
       <div class="comment_btn"><%= form.submit "コメントする" %></div>
      <% end %>
  </div>
```

エラーが出てこないので、ターミナルを確認すると以下のようになっておりました。

```
Started POST "/cat_main/5/cat_post_comments" for ::1 at 2020-08-20 22:35:20 +0900
Processing by CatPostCommentsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"DgF8MsAPQAqJQzw9GtUoRg5EL+3xWnd9+QZbmGDpo44v4UyauD16C/mKdXhdwP/bSAMmt30ncBV7+/GlDbxlPg==", "cat_post"=>{"cat_post_comment"=>"test\r\n"}, "commit"=>"コメントする", "cat_main_id"=>"5"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/cat_post_comments_controller.rb:4:in `create'
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/controllers/cat_post_comments_controller.rb:4:in `create'
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/cat_post_comments_controller.rb:4:in `create'
No template found for CatPostCommentsController#create, rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 10ms (ActiveRecord: 0.9ms | Allocations: 7721)
```

これだけでは何が原因なのかわからなかったので、render部分の記述のミスを疑い、rootパスや別のバスを入力してみましたが、そもそもそこでエラーが起きていなかったようで、改善はありませんでした。
NO FILEとなっていたマイグレーションファイルもあったので、それはコマンドを使用し削除しましたが同様のエラーで改善はありませんでした。
そこで、binding.pryを使用し、以下のような表示となりました

```
    3: def create
    4:   @cat_post_comment = CatPostComment.create(cat_comment_params)
 => 5:   binding.pry
    6:   if @cat_post_comment.save
    7:     render "/cat_main/#{cat_post_comment.cat_post.id}"
    8:   end
    9: end

[1] pry(#<CatPostCommentsController>)> @cat_post_comment
=> #<CatPostComment:0x00007fc6ba1fe540 id: nil, user_id: 1, cat_post_id: nil, cat_post_comment: "テスト", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
[2] pry(#<CatPostCommentsController>)> @cat_post_comment.save!
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: バリデーションに失敗しました: Cat postを入力してください
from /Users/ayumiuchimura/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/validations.rb:80:in `raise_validation_error'
[3] pry(#<CatPostCommentsController>)> @cat_post_comment.errors.full_messages
=> ["Cat postを入力してください"]
[4] pry(#<CatPostCommentsController>)> @cat_post_comment
=> #<CatPostComment:0x00007fc6ba1fe540 id: nil, user_id: 1, cat_post_id: nil, cat_post_comment: "テスト", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
[5] pry(#<CatPostCommentsController>)>
```

原因としてはcat_post_id: nilがnilとなっているせいであることはわかったのですが、ストロングパラメーター部分のmerge記述方法をparams:cat_post_ids => []に変更したり、mergeではなくpermitに記述をしたりしてみたのですが、記述方法がそもそも間違えているのかsyntaxエラーが起きてしまう状態で、そもそもshowのビューページまで遷移する事ができない状態となってしまっています。

どなたかお分かりになりましたら、教えて頂けますと幸いです。
どうぞ宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ammmyy さん、こんにちは。

エラーの件は、保存の時点で `params[:cat_post_id]`がみつかっていないような挙動に見受けられたので、binding.pry したときに `params`を出力してみて`cat_post_id`が確認してみてはどうでしょうか。

### create -> new

```rb
@cat_post_comment = CatPostComment.create(cat_comment_params)
```

createをつかうと、このメソッドの時点でDBへの保存が実行されてしまいます。
newをつかうようにしてみてください。

```
@cat_post_comment = CatPostComment.new(cat_comment_params)
```

もうすこし踏み込むと、ここで作られるcat_post_commentはcurrent_userが持つデータになるとおもうので、Userモデルの関連をつかうとRailsらしくなります。

### 関連を使う方法

```
@cat_post_comment = current_user.cat_post_comments.build(cat_comment_params)
```

この書き方をした場合、`cat_comment_params`でuser_idをmergeする必要はなくなります。
参考：[Active Record の関連付け - Railsガイド](https://railsguides.jp/association_basics.html#has-many%E3%81%A7%E8%BF%BD%E5%8A%A0%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B%E3%83%A1%E3%82%BD%E3%83%83%E3%83%89-collection-build-attributes)

Comment: Uekiさん
お返事頂きありがとうございます。
仰る通りcreateアクションのコードを以下の通りに変更し、mergeのuser_idを削除すると次に進む事ができました！！ `@cat_post_comment = current_user.cat_post_comments.build(cat_comment_params)` また、他の問題も起きてしまいましたが、それは解消させることができました。
本当に大変助かりました！ありがとうございました！！！